# Access ROWID to avoid AutoIncrement in SQLite.Net?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

In a `Xamarin.Forms` app using `SQLite.Net`, the following code works:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(45)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I remove the `AutoIncrement` attribute, on the second `database.Insert` I get an SQLiteException of type Constraint (even after resetting the simulator).

However, the SQLite docs at https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html emphasise that, for performance reasons, `AutoIncrement` should be avoided when possible. The docs suggest that `AutoIncrement` can be avoided using `rowId`. Is there a way to access `rowID` in SQLite.Net?

******** EDIT: ********
The text of the exception is:

```cs
In Main DatabaseException: In OnStart DatabaseException: In Initialise  DatabaseException: In UpsertAsync<T>  ---> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: Constraint
at SQLite.Net.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery (System.Object[] source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj, System.String extra, System.Type objType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

And my insert code is as follows:

```cs
db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetAsyncConnection ();
MyClass mc = new MyClass()
{
    Name = "Hello World!"
};
await UpsertAsync<MyClass> ( mc );
...
...

public async Task<int> UpsertAsync<T> (T row)
// Update a row, of if the row does not exist then insert it
// Returns the Id of the row
{
    try
    {   
        using (IDisposable releaser = await locker.LockAsync ()) 
        {
            Type t = row.GetType ();
            int rowId = Convert.ToInt32 ((t.GetRuntimeProperty("Id")).GetValue (row));      // Get row.Id at runtime using PropertyInfo
            if (rowId != 0) 
            {
                await db.UpdateAsync (row).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
                return rowId;
            } 
            else 
            {
                await db.InsertAsync (row).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
                rowId = Convert.ToInt32 ((t.GetRuntimeProperty ("Id")).GetValue (row));
                return rowId;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DatabaseException ( "In UpsertAsync<T> ", ex);
    }
}
```

This gets the exception in the absence of `AutoIncrement` and works correctly with `AutoIncrement`.

Note: It seems that indexes start at 1 with `AutoIncrement` and at 0 without it. That exposes a bug in my Upsert code where it tests for a `rowId` of 0, when there is no `AutoIncrement`, but that bug is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: You should show your insert code. Remove AutoIncrement and don't set Id on inserts. Then Id is the same as rowid.

Comment: @Paul, I don't think I am setting Id on inserts. (Insert code shown in edit above.)